# Failed to find agents in Mesos-Master

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mesos

I'm running sample spark job via Mesos-Cluster(1 master , 2 Salves) runs on Ubuntu 16.10

Mesos-Master UI the agents tab i cant see any Resource Allocation for a particular agent. I dont see any confirmation in Masters logs when new agent is added.

**Master logs**

```
[15:58:25 master.cpp:4836] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-O786 ] for framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:27 http.cpp:1115  ] HTTP GET for /master/state?jsonp=angular.callbacks._8 from 192.168.1.237:54674 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'
[15:58:28 master.cpp:7305] Sending 1 offers to framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:28 master.cpp:4836] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-O787 ] for framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:29 http.cpp:1115  ] HTTP GET for /master/state?jsonp=angular.callbacks._a from 192.168.1.237:54674 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'
[15:58:30 master.cpp:7305] Sending 1 offers to framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:30 master.cpp:4836] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-O788 ] for framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:33 master.cpp:7305] Sending 1 offers to framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:33 master.cpp:4836] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-O789 ] for framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:34 http.cpp:1115  ] HTTP GET for /master/state?jsonp=angular.callbacks._c from 192.168.1.237:54674 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'
[15:58:35 http.cpp:1115  ] HTTP GET for /master/state?jsonp=angular.callbacks._6 from 192.168.1.237:54674 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'
[15:58:35 master.cpp:7305] Sending 1 offers to framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:35 master.cpp:4836] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-O790 ] for framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:37 http.cpp:1115  ] HTTP GET for /master/state?jsonp=angular.callbacks._a from 192.168.1.237:54674 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'
[15:58:38 master.cpp:7305] Sending 1 offers to framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:38 master.cpp:4836] Processing DECLINE call for offers: [ e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-O791 ] for framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 (wordCount) at scheduler-8c865905-3329-41e9-bb80-7638a5c54a40@192.168.1.237:42131
[15:58:39 http.cpp:1115  ] HTTP GET for /master/state?jsonp=angular.callbacks._c from 192.168.1.237:54674 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'
[15:58:40 master.cpp:6990] Performing explicit task state reconciliation for 1 tasks of framework 417e3708-25d8-46fd-9896-51bcdb750f03-0
```

**Slave logs**

```
Failed to fetch '/usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7': Failed to copy '/usr/local/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7': exited with status 1
End fetcher log for container 11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e
[fetcher.cpp:558] Failed to run mesos-fetcher: Failed to fetch all URIs for container '11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e' with exit status: 256
[slave.cpp:5048] Container '11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e' for executor '1' of framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 failed to start: Failed to fetch all URIs for container '11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e' with exit status: 256
[containerizer.cpp:2102] Destroying container 11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e in FETCHING state
[linux_launcher.cpp:505] Asked to destroy container 11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e
[linux_launcher.cpp:548] Using freezer to destroy cgroup mesos/11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e
[cgroups.cpp:2692] Freezing cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e
[cgroups.cpp:1405] Successfully froze cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e after 2.626816ms
[cgroups.cpp:2710] Thawing cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e
[cgroups.cpp:1434] Successfully thawed cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer/mesos/11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e after 2.189056ms
[containerizer.cpp:2508] Container 11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e has exited
[slave.cpp:5168] Executor '1' of framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 exited with status 1
[slave.cpp:4215] Handling status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: adad1443-e464-462f-b199-7f5545c30ba9) for task 1 of framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 from @0.0.0.0:0
[containerizer.cpp:1917] Ignoring update for unknown container 11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e
[status_update_manager.cpp:323] Received status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: adad1443-e464-462f-b199-7f5545c30ba9) for task 1 of framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000
[slave.cpp:4655] Forwarding the update TASK_FAILED (UUID: adad1443-e464-462f-b199-7f5545c30ba9) for task 1 of framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000 to master@192.168.1.237:5050
[status_update_manager.cpp:395] Received status update acknowledgement (UUID: adad1443-e464-462f-b199-7f5545c30ba9) for task 1 of framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000
[slave.cpp:5268] Cleaning up executor '1' of framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000
[gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/4e98bf77-8b4a-43ab-a79b-12b63c1b18df-S3/frameworks/e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000/executors/1/runs/11ab854c-590e-49da-937b-e5dd5084f36e' for gc 6.99998930747556days in the future
[slave.cpp:5356] Cleaning up framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000
[gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/4e98bf77-8b4a-43ab-a79b-12b63c1b18df-S3/frameworks/e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000/executors/1' for gc 6.99998930613333days in the future
[gc.cpp:55] Scheduling '/var/lib/mesos/slaves/4e98bf77-8b4a-43ab-a79b-12b63c1b18df-S3/frameworks/e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000' for gc 6.99998930488593days in the future
[status_update_manager.cpp:285] Closing status update streams for framework e9377bc9-92a2-47bd-b12b-1525c1233371-0000
```

what are changes to be made in the Installation..??

Comment: What exacly is your problem? Can you show screens to present what is not correct? Probably there is no allocation on agent because no task is running.

Comment: Two things here..
1. When an agent is added to the cluster, I don't see any confirmation in Master-logs(like a new agent have been detected or added with ip 192.xxx.x.xxx)
2. Unable to fetch and copy Executor.Uri  while running the spark job..
Can you suggest me changes required to run the job sucessfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compare your startup settings with working settings for me:

- Zookeeper is running on machine 10.94.40.57 with 3 instances
- Standalone mesos-master is running on machine 10.94.40.35
- Mesos-agent is running on machine 10.94.40.20

Started mesos-master with next parameters:

```
./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=10.94.40.35 --zk=zk://10.94.40.57:4181,10.94.40.57:5181,10.94.40.57:6181/mesos --work_dir=/tmp/mesos-master-35 --quorum=1
```

Started mesos-agent with next parameters:

```
./bin/mesos-agent.sh --ip=10.94.40.20 --master=10.94.40.35:5050 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos-agent --no-systemd_enable_support
```